# How do I camel case a snake-case string except for the first letter?

Tags: bash, sed, string

I'm using bash shell.  I have used this to convert a string from snake case to camel case ...

```
$ echo "this_is_the_string" | sed -r 's/(^|_)([a-z])/\U\2/g'
ThisIsTheString
```

However, what if I want to keep the first letter lower case?  That is, I would want "this_is_the_string" to conver to just

```
thisIsTheString
```

Comment: the first letter is not preceded by an underscore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
$ echo "this_is_the_string" | sed -E 's/_([a-z])/\U\1/g'
thisIsTheString
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
$ string=this_is_the_string
$ set -o extendedglob
$ print -r -- ${string//(#b)_(?)/$match[1]:u}
thisIsTheString
```

Not limited to Latin/Roman let alone ASCII letters and would also remove the `_` in front of non-letters:

```
$ string=pi_aka_π_is_3dot14_and_a_Bit
$ print -r -- ${string//(#b)_(?)/$match[1]:u}
piAkaΠIs3dot14AndABit
```

If your string has sequences of two or more `_`s, you may need to adapt depending on what you want to do about them.

Portably with POSIX utilities, you could do:

```
awk -- '
  BEGIN {
    s = ARGV[1]
    while (match(s, "_."))
      s = substr(s, 1, RSTART - 1) \
          toupper(substr(s, RSTART + 1, 1)) \
          substr(s, RSTART + 2)
    print s
  }' "$string"
```

(`--` not needed POSIXly but needed by older versions of busybox `awk`).

Or use `perl`:

```
perl -CLAO -le 'print $ARGV[0] =~ s/_(.)/\U$1/gr' -- "$string"
```

The `\U` IIRC is from `ex`/`vi` in the 80s. Some `sed` implementations including GNU `sed` also support it, not in the POSIX `sed` specification. `-CLAO` is to treat the `A`rguments as UTF-8 and `O`utput in UTF-8 if the `L`ocale uses UTF-8 (`locale charmap` outputs UTF-8), `zsh` will work with the user's locale characters whatever they are and even still work when the string contains sequences of bytes that can't be decoded in characters. With `awk`, YMMV.

Comment: A `-CLAO` is equivalent to a shorter `-C98`. But I fail to understand why leaving STDIN (`-I`) and STDERR (`-E`) out of the UTF-8 encoding is the correct way to do it. So, perhaps you meant to use `-CLAS (or `-C103`) or even `-CLASD` (or `-C127`).