# PascalCase to lowercase-hyphen

Tags: bash, rename

I am new to renaming and have many files and folders in pascal case that I would like to convert to lower case, separated by a hyphen. I would like to run the command on both files and folders, recursively.

Eg.

- `MyFile.txt` becomes `my-file.txt`
- `MyPhoto.jpg` becomes `my-photo.jpg`

However:

- `ABird.jpg` should remain unchanged
- `USBDisk` should remain unchanged
- for `MyUSBDisk`, I'd be happy with either My-USBDisk or my-USBDisk I have another command to turn all uppercase to lowercase, so the most important thing before that is putting the hyphen in the right place

My attempt did not work:

```
find /path/directory -depth -exec rename 's/\([A-Z]\)/-\L\$1/g' {} \;
```

How to solve? I am using Linux Mint 21.

Comment: How should `ABird.jpg` and `USBDisk.png` be handled?

Comment: They can stay unchanged.

Comment: See [How do I camel case a snake-case string except for the first letter?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/715641) for the reverse

Comment: What about `MyUSBDisk`?

Comment: I'd be happy with either My-USBDisk or my-USBDisk
I have another command to turn all uppercase to lowercase, so the most important thing before that is putting the hyphen in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> rename 's/\([A-Z]\)/-\L\$1/g'
> ```

A couple of things. Perl regexes are closer to POSIX extended regexes than basic regexes, and `\(`/`\)` matches literal parenthesis, while grouping is done without the backslashes. Also, `\$` makes the `$` literal on the right hand side, `$1` is the captured group. That expression would also catch initial uppercase letters, giving you a dash at the start.

Something like this would turn `FooBar` into `foo-bar` (just the rename part here):

```
rename 's/([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])/$1-\L$2/g; s/^([[:upper:]])/\L$1/;' ...
```

But would also turn `USBDisk.img` into `uSBDisk.img`. You could add negative lookahead checks to inhibit the replacement if there's another uppercase letter after the first. This would leave `USBDisk.img` alone, but would still turn `DiskONE.img` into `diskONE.img`.

```
rename 's/([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])(?![[:upper:]])/$1-\L$2/g; s/^([[:upper:]])(?![[:upper:]])/\L$1/;' ...
```

Or skip the whole thing if there are two uppercase letters in a row anywhere in the filename:

```
rename 'unless (/[[:upper:]]{2}/) { s/([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])/$1-\L$2/g; s/^([[:upper:]])/\L$1/ }' ...
```

You might want to test with `rename -n -v` first to review the changes without doing them.

Of course, that still makes `Foo-Bar.jpg` turn into `foo-Bar.jpg`, but I'll leave fixing that as an exercise for now...

---

To run `rename` with `find`, you'll need to add the appropriate `-exec` syntax, e.g.

```
find /path/directory -depth -exec rename '...' {} \;
```

Or with `-exec {} +`, to give multiple filenames to `rename` in one pass:

```
find /path/directory -depth -exec rename '...' {} +
```

Like Stéphane commented, you probably want to limit the renames to just the filename part. Either add the `-d` option to `rename` or switch  to `-execdir` instead of `-exec`. (Nonstandard, GNU/BSD)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it is not happy. Typing the following yields an error.
`find /path/directory -depth -exec rename 's/([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])(?![[:upper:]])/$1-\L$2/g; s/^([[:upper:]])(?![[:upper:]])/\L$1/;'`

`find: missing argument to `-exec'`

If I remove `-exec` and -`depth` then it says `find: ‘rename’: No such file or directory`

Comment: You'd need to do the substitution on the basename only. Some `rename` variants have `-d` for that.

Comment: @ItHertz you're missing the depth level like `-depth 1`

Comment: @ItHertz, right, I only showed the `rename` part. For `find` you need the usual boilerplate, i.e. `find ... -exec rename ... {} \;` or `find ... -exec rename ... {} +`. The braces and semicolon or plus are part of the syntax of `find` here, and unrelated to `rename`.

Comment: @phuclv, plain `-depth` means to change the processing order of find so that it processes files before the containing directory (`./foo/a` before `./foo`), instead of the opposite. BSDs have `-depth <N>` too to limit the recursion depth, but e.g. GNU only has `-mindepth <N>`/`-maxdepth <N>`

Comment: Beware that with `-execdir`, on BSDs, the file names don't start with `./` so you get a command injection vulnerabilities with some `rename` variants (like the one from current versions of `File::Rename`) unless you do `-execdir rename -- '...' {} +`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, oh, that's inconvenient

Comment: @ilkkachu great that now makes it run, with one issue: MyUSBDisk does not become My-USBDisk (or my-USBDisk)

Comment: @ItHertz, yes, I wasn't sure how you wanted to deal with those. That would need  adding a rule like `s/([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]][[:upper:]])/$1-$2/` or something (without the lowercasing `\L`), but I can't test test it further now

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -n '(**/)(*[[:lower:]][[:upper:]]*~*[[:upper:]](#c2)*)' \
       '$1${${2//(#b)([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])/$match[1]-$match[2]}:l}'
```

Where we rename the files that have at least one `<lower><upper>` sequence but no `<upper><upper>`, inserting a `-` between lower and upper case characters and converting the whole file to lowercase.

(`-n` here is for dry-run).